# Closing a kendo ui mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

How can i close a kendo ui mobile view and also unload all its content. This view contains a youtube video that needs to be stopped / unload once a user click on the back button at the top of the view or on android using the physical back button on the device?

Here is the code to my view, but i can't seems to get the view to close. When i use the back button the view goes away but it content does not unload.

```
    <div data-role="view" id="showpostlayout" data-layout="defaultlayout" data-reload="true">
<div data-role="header">
    <div data-role="navbar"><a data-click="closePost" data-role="button" data-align="right">Close</a> </div>
  </div>       
  <div id="mypost">

 </div>
</div>



        <script>
         function closePost() {

             $("#showpostlayout").kendoMobileModalView("close");

        }   
        </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by content does not unload? does the video keeps playing and you can hear the sound?

Comment: When I use the back button it navigate away from the view but the video keeps playing I can still hear the sound while in other view

Comment: I tried to use the modalView of kendo ui mobile in many places. Everytime I change my mind and use a normal view instead of modalView. Anyway, I would recommend you replace the current view to something empty with app.Replace (don't use back button or app.Navigate in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Its stated in the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/modalview)

```
<script>
     function closePost() {
       $("#showpostlayout").data("kendoMobileModalView").close();
     }
</script>
```

give it a whirl.